Raydium SDK V1 Frok
I am confused about Raydium dex. I need help
I forked the Raydium DEX repository the Raydium SDK V1 demo and am currently working on it. Is this approach viable considering that Raydium is now operating on V2? Can we live the V1? If I want to convert V1 to V2, are the functions used in V1 easily convertible?
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo
